# My AJAX call is not retrieving any data, just "undefined"

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, mashape

I had this working when calling the API for a random movie quote generator on Mashape.com. My initial intention was to build an app that would generate bible quotes. I'm using this marketplace page https://market.mashape.com/acg/uncovered-treasure#random. I'm not getting any errors in the console, just this:

```
getNewQuote()
​
arguments: null
​
caller: null
​
length: 0
​
name: "getNewQuote"
​
prototype: Object { … }
​
__proto__: function ()
quote1.js:5:9
OPTIONSXHR
https://uncovered-treasure-v1.p.mashape.com/random
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 170ms]
GETXHR
https://uncovered-treasure-v1.p.mashape.com/random
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 178ms]
undefined
quote1.js:13:11
undefined
```

I can't figure out why I'm not retrieving the data (text, context) I'm calling in the function displayQuote. What am I doing wrong?

Jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      //function to call a quote and bible verse
    function getNewQuote() {
        console.log(getNewQuote);
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://uncovered-treasure-v1.p.mashape.com/random",
        data: {},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function displayQuote(data) {
            //display the quote 
          $("#quote").html(data.text);
          console.log(data.text);
          //display the book the bible verse is being taken from 
          $("#author").html("-" + data.context);
          console.log(data.context);
          //commented the Tweet button out until I can get the quotes to work
          //   function tweetQuote() {
          //     var twitterURL =
          //       'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=quotes,freeCodeCamp&related=freecodecamp&text="';
          //     var quote = $("#quote").html();
          //     var author = $("#author").html();
          //     twitterURL += text + " " + context;
          //     $("#tweet").attr("href", twitterURL);
          //   }
        },
        //error message to display if the call does not work
        error: function() {
          prompt("Try again, God is on your side.");
        },
        //Mashape authorization and key
        beforeSend: function setHeader(xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader(
            "X-Mashape-Key",
            "[API-KEY]"
          );
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        }
      });
    }
    //call a new quote each time the button is clicked
    $("#get-quote").on("click", getNewQuote());
    // console.log(getNewQuote);
  })
```

Comment: added an answer for you see if it helps

Comment: What:s on the server side? On page ready the ajax content might not be available yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are trying to access the `data.context` whereas the API returns in the format `data.results`.

[image: ![![enter image description here]

The `results` is an array which has records on each index so you need to replace the  `data.context` and `data.text` statements in your ajax `success` function with

```
data.results[0].context;
```

and

```
data.results[0].text;
```

respectively

and if there are multiple records returned via API then you need to use the `for in` loop like this

```
var results = data.results;

for (result in results) {
    console.log(data.results[result].context);
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I did see that I was getting the array plus relevant info in the console log but couldn't figure out how to parse it. Thank you so much! That worked!

Comment: you are welcome @Angel do mark the answer as correct if it worked for you.